# Using libjingle 0.5.x for P2P with self-provided signaling

Tags: p2p, libjingle

Can someone provide a small chunk of code based on libjingle 0.5.x where I can see how I could establish a P2P channel for transmitting data, without using XMPP? I intend to provide signaling via either a non-XML-based protocol, or via a non-libjingle XMPP library.

For starters, I'd like to learn more about how libjingle functions, and such an example would be the best way for me to do so.

Here's my research so far:

- [Maemo documentation: How To Use STUN In Applications](http://maemo.org/development/documentation/manuals/3-x/howto_use_stun_bora/) - uses libjingle 0.3.x
- [GNAT](http://code.google.com/p/gnat/) - uses XMPP signaling, uses libjingle 0.4.x
- [Chromium Remoting](http://google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#hfE6470xZHk/remoting/DEPS&d=0) - too complex for my tastes, uses libjingle 0.5.x
- [libjingle-test](https://bitbucket.org/ivucica/libjingle-test) - my experiments so far, uses libjingle 0.5.x